# Connect to Parse to herokuapp.com/parse server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

Since parse is now closing I have switched my database using MongoLab & Heroku using nodejs with Heroku.

Parse makes it easy to connect to your new Database in iOS using ParseUI to point my server ".herokuapp.com/parse".

The question I have is now I want to point to this server using javascript. How do I use parse to get its database at my ".herokuapp.com/parse" database using javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how to set the serverURL, it can be done in the javascript sdk like this:

```
Parse.initialize('appId');
Parse.serverURL = 'https://myappid.herokuapp.com/parse';
```

This is only required if you are using the javascript sdk in the browser however. In nodejs, `parse-server` exports an already initialized js sdk as the global variable `Parse` which can be used from everywhere.